# How to submit form with disabled button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not sure how to explain this, but I want to force a form to check the required fields before doing the onSubmit. This works fine with a normal button, but stops working if the button is disabled. This is something similar to what I have:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="form">
  <input required type="text"/>
  <input required type="text"/>
</form>

<MyButton type="submit" form="form" disabled={!allFieldsAreFilled}>
  Submit
</MyButton>
```

So let's say I fill the first input and hit "Enter". The button is still disabled but I want it to show me that the next field is required. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @steveo314 not what I'm looking for but thanks.

Comment: You can't submit with a disabled button. What is the purpose of disabling the button if you want the user to be able to submit again?

Comment: Hitting enter won't work with a submit button that is actually disabled so you need to disable the button "visually". As in, add a style like `pointer-events: none;` to it, make the color gray, etc. *However*: if you change your code so the field requirements are checked *while the user is typing*, you can enable the button in real time and the whole problem disappears. Add `onInput` to your inputs and use it to update `allFieldsAreFilled`

Comment: @SinanYaman I don't really want to submit it, just to check for the next required field.

Comment: So you want to show the error inputs one by one, on each submit; but disable the button if some fields are empty? You can show all the inputs with error at once, perhaps.

Comment: @ChrisG I see, I guess I will just style the button then. Thanks!